# WildFly EJB UnknownSessionID

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, stateful-session-bean

I just started learning ejb and now have problems. 
My ejb code is

```
@Stateful
@StatefulTimeout(value=80, unit=TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class HelloWorldBean 
    {
        int i = 0;
        public int SayHello()
        {
            return i++;
        }
    }
```

It's only for testing. Ok, so, after 80 sec I get problem from WildFly

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: WFLYEJB0168: Could not find EJB with id UnknownSessionID [5156495653657051576570495270526865695251507057526654654868486852]
```

1) I thought that after 80 sec ejb should be deleted and after refresh page I'll get new instance. Or after 80 sec instance going to passivation (saving on hard drive) ?

2) What is this problem with UnknownSessionID? Why WildFly doesn't want assign ID to session ?

3) With this code example - Why if I use two different browsers at the same time I have the same instance? I thought stateful bean works as one_bean-to-one_user ? So in Google Chrome and Firefox, for example, I should start from i=0 and shouldn't have any similar data between browser sessions

I'll be appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1) The specification says exactly that removal will happen after a stateful timeout. Wildfly follows the EJB specification.
2) An Unknown session ID is a way of saying that the bean does not exist.
3) You must have been using the same servlet to access the bean code above. This means that you must have been using just a single client to access the bean.